# Is there equivalence in Hilbert's theorem on noetherian Rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

In a course about commutative algebra, I came across the following theorem:

$$\text{If $R$ is a noetherian ring, then $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is noetherian.}$$

I can't help but wonder, if the converse is also true. Namely, if $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is noetherian, then $R$ is noetherian itself?

Intuitively this would make sense for me, but I know that modules sometimes behave in some strange ways. It seems fishy, since I can't find this statement anywhere online or in my notes. And if such a statement were true, I should be able to find it somewhere...

An intuitive reason for this to be true, would be that if $R$ is non-noetherian, one can find a sequence of ideals $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \dots \subset R$, which never come to a halt. Now to generate a corresponding sequence in the $R[X]$, we just take the ideals $I_k'$, generated by $X$ and the generators of $I_k$, which shows that $R[X]$ cannot be noetherian.

Another idea would be via morphism $f: R[X_1,\dots,X_n] \rightarrow R$ ; $ f \mapsto f(0,\dots,0)$. This is clearly surjective, therefore induces an isomorphism $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]/\ker(f) \simeq R$, which in turn implies that $R$ is noetherian.

Does this indeed hold, and do the "proofs" work?

Comment: Your second idea gives a perfectly correct proof. Are you not convinced by the arguments you gave ?

Comment: I've linked this question to another question, where, curiously enough, there are two answers that roughly correspond to your two proofs (though they are a bit more verbose, in particular, one of them explicitly states what's the ideal $I_k'$ for a given ideal $I_k$. I would probably just say $I_k'$ is the *set of all polynomials in $R[X]$ with the constant term in $I_k\subset R$*). However, your proofs are good and clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the link, somehow I couldn't find it. Generally I am confident in my arguments, but at the same time it happens often that one overlooks some minor details, screwing the whole argument up :)